# Elasticsearch 7.11 connection refused using Devilbox

Tags: magento2.4, elasticsearch, linux, containers

I'm starting the Elasticsearch 7.11 in my linux, and it works when i run `curl -XGET localhost:9200` **INSIDE MY LINUX**. But the issue is, i'm trying to access this Elasticsearch service started in my linux, **inside a Devilbox docker**, and when i run `curl -XGET localhost:9200` on the CLI inside Devilbox, it returns 'connection refused'·

Already tried to change network.host to 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and it doesn't worked.
Already tried to change discovery hosts to ["0.0.0.0", "[::1]"] and it doesn't worked too.

When i starts the service in my linux and runs `curl -XGET localhost:9200` it returns:
[image]

When i tried INSIDE DEVILBOX it returns:
[image]

I'm triyng this way, because installing the elasticsearch inside devilbox container didn't worked. So i'm using the elasticsearch service outside the devilbox container.

Comment: did you try with change port number?

Comment: @S.P tried to change port on elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml, but when i starts the service, it remains on the same port(9200). There is a specif port to change ?

Comment: use adminmagento private IP instead of localhost? curl -XGET private-ip:9200

Comment: @BilalUsean on devilbox it returns `Connection refused`, in the linux it returns the same. But running in the linux with 127.0.0.1:9200 it works.

Comment: after update elasticsearch port, did u restart elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this issue by changing network.host to 0.0.0.0 and discovery_seed.host to ["localhost", "127.0.0.1"] on the file elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Search for the line that contains network.host, uncomment it, and change the value to 0.0.0.0.
Set the network host to 0.0.0.0 to listen on all interfaces and make it available publicly,
Incase you want to configure this to be private/local to your machine. You will have to set the network.host to 127.0.0.1, so the content is not public.

**sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml**

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
http.port: 9200
```

If your server only has 8GB of RAM, you must edit this setting.
Open jvm.options:

**sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options**

Now change the Xms and Xmx values to 2g:
/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options

```
-Xms2g
-Xmx2g
```